# pickle.dump dumps nothing when appending to file

Tags: python, file, pickle

User may give a bunch of urls as command line args. All URLs given in the past are serialized with pickle. The script checks all given URLs, if they are unique then they are serialized and appended to a file. At least that's what should be happening. Nothing is being appended. However when I open the file in write mode,the new, unique URL is written. So what gives? Code is:

```
def get_new_urls():
    if(len(urls.URLs) != 0): # check if empty
        with open(urlFile, 'rb') as f:
            try:
                cereal = pickle.load(f)
                print(cereal)
                toDump = []
                for arg in urls.URLs:
                    if (arg in cereal):
                        print("Duplicate URL {0} given, ignoring it.".format(arg))
                    else:
                        toDump.append(arg)
            except Exception as e: 
                print("Holy bleep something went wrong: {0}".format(e))
            return(toDump)

urlsToDump = get_new_urls() 
print(urlsToDump)
# TODO: append new URLs
if(urlsToDump):
    with open(urlFile, 'ab') as f:
        pickle.dump(urlsToDump, f)

# TODO check HTML of each page against the serialized copy
with open(urlFile, 'rb') as f:
    try:
        cereal = pickle.load(f)
        print(cereal)
    except EOFError: # your URL file is empty, bruh
        pass
```

Comment: While originality is nice, remember, this is a kid friendly website ;-(

Comment: "ain't dumpin' no thing" is just **wrong**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pickle writes out the data you give it in a special format, e.g. it will write some header/metadata/etc, to the file you give it.

It is not intended to work this way; concatenating two pickle files doesn't really make sense. To achieve a concatenation of your data, you'd need to first read whatever is in the file into your `urlsToDump`, then update your `urlsToDump` with any new data, and then finally dump it out again (overwriting the whole file, not appending).

Answer (score -1):

After

```
with open(urlFile, 'rb') as f:
```

you need a `while` loop, to repeatedly unpickle (repeatedly read) from the file until hitting EOF.